# How do I interact with <select> and JavaScript - Display Form Results

Tags: javascript, html

Here is the jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/OnatOhE/3/ (just right click, view source to see source code)

I'm trying to display the results that the user chose on the same page after hitting the button.  I've messed around with this for a while and I haven't found a simple way to do this.

All help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: The error console is your friend

Comment: Please include the most important part of the code you're having problems with in your question. It's always better to get a first impression of what the problem is before having to click any URLs. The code doesn't have to be a lot (in fact, short and to the point is better), but just a bit of code to give us an impression of your problem is useful.

Comment: What javascript have you tried? I don't see any javascript in the example

Comment: Please [avoid questions with links to code, but no actual code](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149890/209031).  The question should be entirely self contained.  If you had of happened to use the more popular `jsfiddle.net`, this question would not have been allowed as is, but there's not **yet** a rule filtering just jsbin posts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if you look at any documentation for javascript libraries they would have an example of this but a very very simple way to do it could be like this using jQuery...

```
$( "#favColor" ).change(function() {
    $("#bottomText").append(' '+$("#favColor option:selected").val());
});
```

You add to this by making a function that finds all select boxes and does the above to all of them, instead of having 5 functions that do the same thing.

See:
http://api.jquery.com/change/ 
http://api.jquery.com/val/